# Call methods without metamask?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, metamask

Is there anyway to call Web3js or Contract methods with Non-Ethereum browser so the website could at least show some information to guest/anonymous user? I'm new to this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a JSON RPC Provider, basically you connect your web3 provider to a node

If you do something like:

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
const url = 'http://localhost:8545'
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(url)
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

Then you can do something like (I'm not testing this but you should get the idea)

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(...)
contract.methods.myMethod.call(params)
```

For more info check this:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3.html#id4
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call